# Almost sure convergence, uniformly integrable and L1 convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, martingales

I am learning the convergence of martingale. Then I saw a theorem from my textbook which implies a theorem in measure theory which states "Let {Xn,n ∈ N} be a sequence of random variables which converges almost surely to a random variable X. Then Xn converges in L1 to X if and only if {Xn, n ∈ N} is uniformly integrable." Is there any proof for this theorem? thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Refer to K L Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory'